# actionscript 3 using the keyboard enter

Tags: events, logging, textinput

I have build a login form using two TextInput fieldds for username and password. I have already created a button which was straightforward. I want the user to have the option of pressing Enter on the keyboard to log in and not click on the button. How do I do that? And, can you please explain what the Event.Change does? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, which is dispatched while the key is pressed.  You could stop listening as soon as this had occurred.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html

And then look up the keyCode for the Enter key (13).  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Example:

```
public static const ENTER:int = 13;
public var pressedEnter:Boolean = false;

public function start():void
{
    passwordField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, 
        false, 0, true);
}

private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (!pressedEnter && ENTER == e.keyCode) {
        trace("TODO: Enter form.");
        pressedEnter = true;
    }
}
```

Event.CHANGE dispatches every time text field changing, or an option in a widget changing to a different option.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ethan i tested your code out and it worked!! Great stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, key_down);


function key_down(e:Event):void
{
    //whatever you want

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!